# How to install a git cloned package in arch

Tags: git, arch

How can I install a package which is cloned from github? there is no instillation file in many of them!

I run `git clone https://aur.archlinux.org/jcal-git.git`

then when I want to install there is no execution file!
what should I do?

I'd be thankful if you give me some advises for this.

Answer (score 0):

check this,https://github.com/ashkang/jcal/tree/master/sources

```
Installation
============
Run ./autogen.sh to make `configure` script for you.  Then follow common
package installation routine as described in INSTALL.

If you want pyjalali package too, you can either pass `--enable-pyjalali`
option to ./configure script or after installing libjalali use provided
`setup.py` directly:

# cd jcal/sources
# python setup.py install
```

Comment: I used link in https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/jcal-git/?O=0&PP=10 but it differs from what you gave, I'd like to learn installing AUR packages.

Comment: should be the same, your git repo is `https://github.com/persiancal/jcal` which is a fork from `https://github.com/ashkang/jcal`